# When did Ash catch all his Tauros

Tags: pokemon

Was re-watching every episode of the first season and suddenly he had a bunch of Tauros. I was like "when did this happen?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ash caught his Tauros in [Episode 35](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP035), however the episode was banned in many countries

> This episode was banned due to the prevalent usage of handguns throughout the episode. Kaiser, the Safari Zone warden, points a gun at Ash's head a couple times, and even shoots the gun at Team Rocket at one point. **The banning of this episode left a major plot hole and a continuity error in the English dub, as this was the episode where Ash captured all 30 of his Tauros**. As this is the Safari Zone episode, it also makes the Safari Zone unseen in the English anime, though it is mentioned in the two episodes that took place before it.
>
> [Source](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Banned_episodes#List_of_banned_episodes_2)